# Angular2 pipe regex

Tags: regex, angular, pipe

I did research, but I didn't find good article about `angular2` `regex` inside `pipe`. I would like to create custom pipe that will trim displaying word.

I have:

```
aaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd(yyyy,pppp.yy)
```

I want display only:

```
cccc.dddd
```

There is always '(' in this word. I would like to use `RegExp` here or maybe it is better way to do this? Question is about how to use `RegExp` in Pipe, not about `RegExp` pattern.

**UPDATE**

[working example (last version)](https://plnkr.co/edit/yAE5xWZj3ixs5X0tWAPH?p=preview)

Comment: In your CustomPipe class, use `return value.split('(')[0];`, or `return value.indexOf('(') > -1 ?  value.split('(')[0] : value;`. See https://plnkr.co/edit/izsHrqYkOnXyQIyFCFub?p=info

Comment: Yeah, thats what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not really need to use any regex here, you can split with `(` and get the first item:

In your `CustomPipe` class, use

```
return value.indexOf('(') > -1 ? value.split('(')[0] : value;
```

See the [updated plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/izsHrqYkOnXyQIyFCFub?p=info).

Another option is to use `value.substring(0,value.indexOf("("))` instead of `value.split('(')[0]`.